# Is it possible to convert a procedural texture into actual geometry?

Tags: mesh, texturing, workflow

As we now have volumetrics in cycles, it's possible to render procedural textures in 3D.

For example, you can render a cube:

[image]

Like this:

[image]

---

However, is it possible to generate an actual mesh based on the intensity of a procedural texture?

I tried to do something like this:

1. Simulate particle system being affected by procedural texture
2. Convert particle system to vertices
3. Mesh using the convex hull modifier

But I failed because:

- I couldn't get the particles to group convincingly based on the intensity of a texture
- The result was concave, so the convex hull operator was not useful.

How can I generate a mesh in this way?

Answer (score 5):

Particle is a nice idea to do this, and it is possible to control the volumetric density by procedual texture:

[image]

[**Demo file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26419)

---

**Edit:**

As MarcClinton mentioned in comment, a nice addon called **[MSMesher](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?284678-MSMesher)** can be a relatively nice solution:

[image]

The result looks similar to metaballs, which means, to generate a sharper shape, further remeshing would be considered.

Comment: Now I just need some way to mesh them.. metaballs?

Comment: Metaball is fine, just sort of overkill.

Comment: The MSMesher Addon might do this for you. Here is a thread on BA.org http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?284678-MSMesher
The authors username is MohamedSakr and there is a video link for Vimeo titled MSMesher Introduction

Comment: @MarcClintDion Ah, I think this is what the OP want. MSMesher seems nice here, although it seems hard to make a sharp-enough result. But we can try using Remesh after that. I think it's less overkill than metaball.

Comment: Well, since you bring it up.  I do remember seeing all quads and they appeared evenly spaced and are well oriented along all three axis.  It looks ideal for Loop Cuts(Ctrl-R). The one big thing I noticed is that all traffic on this thread stopped several months ago.  Maybe someone else will have to take up the maintenance.

Comment: Looks promising! :) I always did want a way to mesh particles for SPH fluid sims..