# Using 2D / 3D textures with volumetrics?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, volumetrics

I've tried multiple times to get clouds into Blender. However, my scene has too many vertices for it to handle objects with multiple subdivision modifiers. I thought that, as an alternative, I could use a texture to tell Blender which parts of the volume were transparent and which parts had volumetric scattering.

However, when I plug my test shader into volume, I get a half transparent, half emission shader instead, though it works fine for the surface. I've tried using the Texture Coordinate node for the texture itself -- it did nothing.

[image: Sorry about the extra stuff included. GIMP has weird exporting issues right now.]

Then I read about 3D textures on [this thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9668/what-are-3d-textures). I tried to find about 3D textures in Blender, which was completely hopeless:

- [3D Volumetric Planetary Clouds in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/3d-volumetric-planetary-clouds-in-cycles)
- [Volumetric gradient based on density?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14560/volumetric-gradient-based-on-density)
- [Is it possible to convert a procedural texture into actual geometry?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6450/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-procedural-texture-into-actual-geometry)
- [cycles volume rendering 3D image texture (CT or MR dataset)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18418/cycles-volume-rendering-3d-image-texture-ct-or-mr-dataset)
- [Creating a texture and normal map from a 3D model / scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8601/creating-a-texture-and-normal-map-from-a-3d-model-scene)
- [3d Textures from Flat texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19436/3d-textures-from-flat-texture)

So my question is: How can I tell Cycles to use textures as a factor for a Mix Node, or how can I generate a 3D texture from a 2D procedural ,and use that in Blender? (And sorry about the extra stuff included in the screenshot. GIMP has weird exporting issues right now.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can use 2D/3D textures with volumetrics.

All procedural cycles textures will be 3D and you can use them for example like this:

[image]

Or you can just project 2D textures on your mesh too, this is the same cube with some mask:

[image]