# How to make 3D volumetric textures in Blender?

Tags: texturing, light, shaders, volumetrics

So let's say I want to make some volumetric fog or something like that. I saw a demo of how to do that in Blender recently, but it relied on the built in 3D textures built into Blender. How do I make my own 3D textures?

I'm very new to volumetric stuff so maybe I'm not even using the right terminology. Any clues?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43648/1853

Comment: And: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23881/1853

Comment: Thanks @cegaton So would it be correct to say that the only way to make 3d textures is procedurally?

Comment: You can use any texture.

Comment: @cegaton right but if you use a 2d texture it's not going to be the same as a 3d texture. 3D texture has to be procedurally generated correct?